# Finding Prime Numbers - "factor" command not found on MacOS

Tags: macos, bash, scripting

I am writing a bash script to find all of the prime numbers less than a given integer.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

BADARGS=65
if [ -z $1 ]
then
   echo "Usage:`basename $0` cannot have a null parameter."
   exit $BADARGS
elif [ $1 -lt 2 ]
then
   echo "Usage:`basename $0` should have the value 2 or more as the parameter."
   exit $BADARGS
fi
TRUE=0
FALSE=
Primes(){
checkPrime=( $(factor $1) ) # this puts factors into array

if [ -z "${checkPrime[2]}" ] # third element is null
then
   return $TRUE
else
   return $FALSE
fi
}
printf "2 "
let "n = 3"
while [ $n -le $1 ]
do
   if Primes $n
   then
       printf "$n "
   fi
       let "n += 2"   
done
printf "\n"

# END
```

I am using MacOS and when I execute the script I receive this error message:

```
Jessicas-MacBook-Pro:Documents jessicalott$ ./primes.sh 10
2 ./primes.sh: line 16: factor: command not found
3 ./primes.sh: line 16: factor: command not found
5 ./primes.sh: line 16: factor: command not found
7 ./primes.sh: line 16: factor: command not found
9
```

I literally starting writing in bash this morning so any help would be appreciated. I think it might have something to do with the fact that I am not using Linux, but I hope that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`factor` is not a standard Unix command. Linux has it. OS X does not.

Comment: Specifically, it's part of the GNU `coreutils` package, which you can probably install using `brew`, `ports`, `fink`, or from source.

Comment: @chepner: If you enter that as an answer, I will vote up your answer and delete mine.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. To point out the obvious, `brew search factor` and `brew cask install factor` will find [the wrong thing (the Factor VM, which isn't even a VM, btw)](http://macappstore.org/factor/). As will searching Apple Store. What you need is `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: @smci: `brew` is also not part of macOS, so `brew install coreutils` cannot work without some prior installation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: True. But Apple App Store is, and it will also show you the Factor VM (without even telling you what it is, or that it's not the droid you're looking for). I suggest you add a one-liner telling people how to install brew, then one for `brew install coreutils`

Comment: Check to see if your Mac system has gfactor; depending on what else you've installed on your system, the GNU utils might be prefixed with 'g'.

Comment: @DMac: `gfactor` is not part of a standard macOS (previously OS X) installation.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in a comment, factor is part of GNU coreutils. You can install coreutils with [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install coreutils
```

After that `factor` can be replaced with `/usr/local/bin/gfactor` in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error using the shorter Homebrew install, but this worked for me:

```
brew install coreutils findutils gnu-tar gnu-sed gawk gnutls gnu-indent gnu-getopt
```

Answer (score 1):

Save this `Makefile` and run `make`. It downloads the sources of `factor` and `primes` from the NetBSD CVS repositories and builds them. If you don't have `curl`, try `make G=wget`.

```
W= http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/games
G= curl -L -R -O
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -O2 -Dlint -D__dead= -DHAVE_OPENSSL

all:    get bin

bin:    factor primes

factor: factor.o pr_tbl.o
    $(CC) -o $@ factor.o pr_tbl.o -lcrypto

primes: primes.o pr_tbl.o pattern.o spsp.o
    $(CC) -o $@ primes.o pr_tbl.o pattern.o spsp.o -lm

clean:
    -rm -f factor primes factor.o pattern.o pr_tbl.o primes.o spsp.o

get:
    $G $W/factor/factor.6
    $G $W/factor/factor.c
    $G $W/primes/pattern.c
    $G $W/primes/primes.6
    $G $W/primes/primes.c
    $G $W/primes/primes.h
    $G $W/primes/pr_tbl.c
    $G $W/primes/spsp.c
```

(Makefile updated to include `spsp.c`)

Also available at https://github.com/lhf/factor

Comment: This seems inferior to installing with a package manager like brew. The code won't know where it came from and thus can never update itself.

Comment: @smci, sure, but my solution has no dependencies.

Comment: True. Is NetBSD's `primes` available in any package on brew, MacOS, Gnu etc? I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: I asked at [Is NetBSD 'primes' utility or equivalent available in any package on MacOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455236/is-netbsd-primes-utility-or-equivalent-available-in-any-package-on-macos)